# Como somar um valor de uma str e depois printar a nova str com o valor modificado?

Tags: python

Quando eu selecionar um XPATH, quero que o programa vá sempre somando o valor em negrito abaixo:

- *//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[**1**]

A minha ideia é pegar uma XPATH base, e modificar um valor especifico nessa XPATH, no caso aquele 1 que está em negrito, quero sempre ir somando aquele número e ir printando a nova XPATH, no caso seria assim a minha ideia:

- //[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1] ->
- //[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2] ->
- //[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3] ->
- //[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4] ->

Tentei fazer dessa maneira, mas sem sucesso:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]'
xpath2 = int(xpath[-2])
soma = xpath2 + 1
print(xpath[-2 == soma])
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques, pelo que eu entendi o cara quer fazer alguma coisa parecido com o que eu coloquei na resposta.

Comment: A minha ideia é pegar uma XPATH base, e modificar um valor especifico nessa XPATH, no caso aquele 1 que está em negrito, quero sempre ir somando aquele número e ir printando a nova XPATH, no caso seria assim a minha ideia:

//[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1] -> //[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2] ->
//[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3] ->
//[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4] ->

Comment: @AugustoVasques, vale a pena complementar com essa informação do `f-string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é fazendo um laço e repetição e "montar" o xpath que deseja.

Segue um exemplo:

```
xpath_pattern = '//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[{}]'
for i in range(3):
    print(xpath_pattern.format(i))
```

Repare que o valor da variável `xpath_pattern` no valor inteiro que deseja incrementar possui um `{}`, esse caractere coringa vai ser interpolado pelo método `format`, dentro do laço, gerando uma nova string com o valor de `i` incrementado por 1 a cada iteração.

Isso vai gerar uma saída da seguinte forma:

```
//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[0]
//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
```

A estratégia aqui foi utilizar o método [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) da classe str.
Utilizei o valor 3 no parâmetro da função range, porém você pode utilizar a função [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) para encontrar o valor do parâmetro corretamente.

Depois basta usar esse padrão para extrair os dados.

#### Uma implementação para Python >= 3.6

Se tiver utilizando a versão do Python >= 3.6 então é possível utilizar o padrão de interpolação [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Segue um exemplo:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(f'//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[{i}]')
```

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementado é uma variações do mesmo [raciocínio dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/540943/137387) porém tem mais uma possibilidade usando um [templates](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#template-strings).

```
from string import Template

s = Template('//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[$idx]')

for i in range(3):
  print(s.substitute(idx=i))
#//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[0]
#//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
#//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
```

Templates fornecem substituições de string mais simples segundo as seguintes regras:

- `$$` é uma forma de escape e é substituído por um único `$`.
- `$identificador` nomeia um marcador de substituição que corresponde a uma chave de mapeamento de "identificador". Por padrão, "identificador" deve ser um identificador Python válido e o primeiro caractere não identificador após o caractere $ encerra essa especificação
- `${identificador}` é equivalente a `$identificador` e é necessário quando caracteres identificadores válidos seguem o marcador de posição, mas não fazem parte do marcador de posição: `${prefixo}ismo`.