# como usar variavel dentro dos colchetes de uma string em python

Tags: python, string

preciso atualizar em cada loop de um while o  numero que fica dentro dos colchetes de um link que é uma string ex:
data-table/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[ **VARIÁVEL** ]/td[1]/div/div[1]/button/span[1]/img")

desde já agradeço.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/540942/112052

Comment: @eduardogarciadeoliveira, Agradeço sua interação mas infelizmente o código não interpreta a variável, EX: data-table/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[+' '+ str(i)+' '+]/td[1]/div/div[1]/button/span[1]/img")

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código que vc está tentando, e uma descrição mais detalhada do erro (de preferência a mensagem de erro que o próprio programa mostra ao executar), pois "não interpreta a variável" está meio vago e difícil de entender. De qualquer forma, viu o link que indiquei acima? Lá tem soluções para o seu problema (que é bem similar, bastando adaptar)

Comment: Obrigado @hkotsubo, excelente a matéria do link que me passou vou estudá-la e encontrar uma solução

Answer (score -3):

Abre e fecha as aspas e concatena as partes com o sinal de +

```
'data-table/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[' + VARIÁVEL + ']/td[1]/div/div[1]/button/span[1]/img'
```